# `ConfigTime` daylight saving update

Tags: time

I'm using an ESP8266 to get clock NTP sync in this manner:

```
void myIOT2::_startNTP(const int gmtOffset_sec, const int daylightOffset_sec, const char *ntpServer)
{
    configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer); //configuring time offset and an NTP server
    while (now() < 1627735850)                                /* while in 2021 */
    {
        delay(20);
    }
    delay(100);
}
```

But now, when daylight saving ended on 31/10/2021, what "flags" code that now daylight saving has ended, and 3600 sec have to reduced (or add) ?

in my case `gmtOffset_sec=2*3600` and `daylightOffset_sec=1*3600` `ntpServer="pool.ntp.org"`

Comment: the SDK adjusts automatically. I use only `configTime(TZ_Europe_Bratislava, "pool.ntp.org");` TZ constants are in TZ.h  in esp8266 core

Comment: @Juraj I guess that ‘TZ_Europe_Bratislava’ encapsulates similar constants as mine. But still my time sync hasn’t updated

Comment: the DST info is not from the NTP server. my esp8266 clock changed time at 3 AM to 2 AM, but it syncs with NTP only once a day

Comment: @Juraj I used my TZ constant, and it worked as you said. Can you please explain why my method did not work as needed?

Comment: @Juraj What should I do in ESP32 ?

Comment: @Juraj NTP was not shifted as needed

Comment: @Juraj TNX, and that relates to my question about ESP32 ( since `TZ.h` belongs to `ESP8266.h`)

Comment: the esp32 has the configTzTime function for timezone. it is missing the TZ.h file. you can copy the TZ.h file or only the string with zone definition for your time zone.

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/14c3798d4ff959254599f2904579412acba3f175/cores/esp8266/TZ.h#L338

Answer (score 1):

Summing @juraj's comments

1. instead of defining UTC+x and Daylight offset, using NTZ instead.
2. While ESP8266 has `TZ.h as part of its core I used relevant TZ as shown.
3. for ESP32: a) replace to `configTzTime` as shown. b) Copy relevant TZ from `TZ.h` for current lib and use as follows.

for ESP8266:
`configTime(TZ_Asia_Jerusalem, ntpServer);`

for ESP32:
`configTzTime(TZ_Asia_Jerusalem, ntpServer);` // Tz value was copied to code